# Make app notifications ring as loudly as the phone

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a the IFTT app set up to send me very important ios notifications. I need it to wake me up at night. How can I make the notification sounds max loudness and ring for as long as a phone ring?

Answer (score 1):

The phone ringing is, technically speaking, a notification sound, and uses the same volume setting as all other notifications (called Ringer Volume).

As far as notification tone length, you would need to contact the app's developer. You cannot set custom tones (at least, outside the app) for 3rd-party iOS apps like you can with Phone, Messages, etc.